# Showing that the left limit exists for a finite measure

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on the $\sigma$-algebra $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.

I am to show that for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ that the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu((-\infty, a_n])$ exists, for every increasing sequence $(a_n)$ with limit $a$.

Here's what I've done so far:

Let $(I_n)$ be an increasing sequence of intervals, with $I_n = (-\infty, a_n]$, then

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mu((-\infty, a_n]) = \mu\left( \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} I_n \right) = \mu((-\infty, a])$$

and so the limit exists for every $a$.

However, an upcoming question makes me think that the limit should be $\mu((-\infty, a))$ instead, if that is the case then what am I doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $a\in \bigcup_{n\ge 1}(-\infty,a_n]$?

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing. Of course it isnt, thanks for the help!